# Large hex values with PHP hexdec

Tags: php, hex

I have some large HEX values that I want to display as regular numbers, I was using hexdec() to convert to float, and I found a function on PHP.net to convert that to decimal, but it seems to hit a ceiling, e.g.:

```
$h = 'D5CE3E462533364B';
$f = hexdec($h);
echo $f .' = '. Exp_to_dec($f);
```

Output: 1.5406319846274E+19 = 15406319846274000000

Result from calc.exe = 15406319846273791563

Is there another method to convert large hex values?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As said on the [hexdec manual page](http://php.net/hexdec):

> The function can now convert values
>   that are to big for the platforms
>   integer type, it will return the value
>   as float instead in that case.

If you want to get some kind of big integer (not float), you'll need it stored inside a string. This might be possible using [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) functions.

For instance, if you look in the comments of the hexdec manual page, you'll find [this note](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php#90309)

If you adapt that function a bit, to avoid a notice, you'll get:

```
function bchexdec($hex)
{
    $dec = 0;
    $len = strlen($hex);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
        $dec = bcadd($dec, bcmul(strval(hexdec($hex[$i - 1])), bcpow('16', strval($len - $i))));
    }
    return $dec;
}
```

*(This function has been copied from the note I linked to; and only a bit adapted by me)*

And using it on your number:

```
$h = 'D5CE3E462533364B';
$f = bchexdec($h);
var_dump($f);
```

The output will be:

```
string '15406319846273791563' (length=20)
```

So, not the kind of big float you had ; and seems OK with what you are expecting:

> Result from calc.exe =
>   15406319846273791563

Hope this help ;-)

*And, yes, user notes on the PHP documentation are sometimes a real gold mine ;-)*

Comment: Thank you muchly. I already had BC Math installed so this got the 'answer' over the GMP solution, but I'm sure both do the job. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

hexdec() switches from int to float when the result is too large to be represented as an int.  If you want arbitrarily long values, you're probably going to have to roll your own conversion function to change the hex string to a [GMP integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).

```
function gmp_hexdec($n) {
  $gmp = gmp_init(0);
  $mult = gmp_init(1);
  for ($i=strlen($n)-1;$i>=0;$i--,$mult=gmp_mul($mult, 16)) {
    $gmp = gmp_add($gmp, gmp_mul($mult, hexdec($n[$i])));
  }
  return $gmp;
}

print gmp_strval(gmp_hexdec("D5CE3E462533364B"));

Output: 15406319846273791563
```

Comment: I would have set this as the answer but I don't have GMP extension installed (although maybe I should).

Answer (score 4):

```
$num = gmp_init( '0xD5CE3E462533364B' ); // way to input a number in gmp
echo gmp_strval($num, 10); // display value in decimal
```

That's the module to use. Convert it to a function and then use on your numbers.

Note: provide these hex numbers as strings so:

```
$num = "0x348726837469972346"; // set variable
$gmpnum = gmp_init("$num"); // gmp number format
echo gmp_strval($gmpnum, 10); // convert to decimal and print out
```

Answer (score 3):

1.5406319846274E+19 is a limited representation of you number. You can have a more complete one by using printf()

```
printf("%u\n", hexdec($h));
```

...will output "15406319846273792000". PHP uses floats for such big numbers, so you may lose a bit of precision. If you have to work with arbitrary precision numbers, you may try the [bcmath extension](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). By splitting the hex into two 32-bit words (which should be safe on most systems) you should be able to get more precision. For instance:

```
$f = bcadd(bcmul(hexdec(substr($h, 0, -8)), 0x100000000), hexdec(substr($h, 8)));
```

...would set $f to 15406319846273791563.

Comment: Just a quick caution on this. This will only work on a 16 character hex anything shorter will give an incorrect result

Answer (score 3):

Convert HEX to DEC is easy.. But, reconstruct back hexadecimal number is very hard.
Try to use [base_convert](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) ..

```
$hexadecimal = base_convert(2826896153644826, 10, 16);
// result: a0b0c0d0e0f1a
```

Comment: At least in my testing base_convert is still converting it to a float I would guess. If you run base_convert("9bdb999850d41000", 16, 10) you get 11230738975248618662 when the true answer should be 11230738975248617472

Answer (score 3):

Run into this issue while storing 64-bit keys in MySQL database. I was able to get a bit perfect conversion to a 64-bit signed integer (PHP limitation) using a few binary operators: (This code is 16x faster than bchexdec function and resulting variables are using half the memory on average).

```
function x64toSignedInt($k){
    $left = hexdec(substr($k,0,8));
    $right = hexdec(substr($k,8,8));
    return (int) ($left << 32) | $right;
}
```

MySQL signed BIGINT datatype is a great match for this as an index or storage in general. HEX(column) is a simple way to convert it back to HEX within the SQL query for use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This solution also uses the BC Math Functions. However, an algorithm is used which does without the bcpow function. This function is a bit shorter and faster than the accepted solution, tested on PHP 7.4.

```
function hexDecBc(string $hex) : string 
{
  for ($dec = '0', $i = 0; $i < strlen($hex); $i++) {
    $dec = bcadd(bcmul($dec,'16'),(string)hexdec($hex[$i]));
  }
  return $dec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable gmp extension. `ext-gmp`

```php
 $number = gmp_strval(gmp_init('0x03....')); // outputs: 1234324....
```

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't `intval(var, base)` take care of it?

From the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/intval).

Comment: var_dump(intval('D5CE3E462533364B', 16)); gets me int 2147483647 ; not really what he expected ^^ ; See the note on the documentation of intval, which says : "The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647."