# Convert 20 byte decimal to 24 byte hexadecimal

Tags: php, hex, 3des, mathematical-expressions

How can I convert a 20 byte decimal (74515898855732498125) to a 24 byte hexadecimal.

This 24 byte hexa output will act as an encryption key for doing TripleDES.

Please help with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Large hex values with PHP hexdec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273484/large-hex-values-with-php-hexdec)

Comment: Try hasing it with Tiger-192 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_(cryptography) )