# Hexadecimal String Incrementation

Tags: php, type-conversion

It might be an easy two lines code but I've spend the last two hours searching and trying every solution out there in vain.

Using PHP 5.6, I want to increment the value of a string that I get from my Database.The string contains an hexadecimal number for example `ffffffff000000000001586f` I want to increment it to get `ffffffff0000000000015870`

I have tried to convert my string with `hexdec` and `dechex` , `String2hex` ... but I always get a wrong result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Large hex values with PHP hexdec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273484/large-hex-values-with-php-hexdec)

Comment: Thanks but not a duplicate as he want to convert his hex to a decimal , my case is different I want to get an hexadecimal representation of the string, I'll try some tricks from the comments though .

Comment: The problem is same -  you can't use bare `hexdec` since it's big numbers.

Comment: That's the point , my problem is that I can't get back that big decimal number to the hexadecimal presentation

Comment: Try those functions from the first comment — http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php#99130

Comment: The conversion seems to be be working but whenever I try to increment the decimal number the hex output become a 0

Comment: Use `bcadd` for adding to decimal, then convert back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using functions from http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php#99130

```
<?php

function bchexdec($hex) {
    if(strlen($hex) == 1) {
        return hexdec($hex);
    } else {
        $remain = substr($hex, 0, -1);
        $last = substr($hex, -1);
        return bcadd(bcmul(16, bchexdec($remain)), hexdec($last));
    }
}

function bcdechex($dec) {
    $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
    $remain = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);

    if($remain == 0) {
        return dechex($last);
    } else {
        return bcdechex($remain).dechex($last);
    }
}

echo bcdechex(bcadd(bchexdec('ffffffff000000000001586f'), 1));
```

https://3v4l.org/fXneg