# PHP hexdec. How to avoid unexpected round down?

Tags: php

It seems that hexdec do round down automatically. I want to avoid it. How can I do it? I use PHP7.

```
<?php
$hex = '0x6252f8774def5e344';
$decimal = hexdec($hex);
echo $decimal; // 1.1335997368159E+20

result:113359973681590000000
expect:113359973681592656708
```

---

Update 1

This might be similar question.
[Large hex values with PHP hexdec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273484/large-hex-values-with-php-hexdec)

---

Update 2 (memo for me)

Ivan mentioned about gmp, the following math extensions might be useful.

Mathematical Extensions
http://php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php

Comment: That seems an issue with floating point numbers, you could try `base_convert('6252f8774def5e344', 16, 10)` instead.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Thank you. I'm checking about base_convert.

Comment: Regarding your "update 1", yep, seems a duplicate, so it'll probably be closed as such if you keep it.

Comment: `base_convert` will **not work**! Look my answer below, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [GMP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php):

> GMP gmp_init ( mixed $number [, int $base = 0 ] )

For your issue:

```
echo gmp_init ( '6252f8774def5e344',16);
```

Solution like this `base_convert('6252f8774def5e344', 16, 10)` will not work =>
 [php.net: base-convert](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.base-convert.php)

> base_convert() may lose precision on large numbers due to properties related to the internal "double" or "float" type used. Please see the Floating point numbers section in the manual for more specific information and limitations.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying it now.

Comment: @zono Is it ok? Can you call function gmp_init? Has been the problem solved?

Comment: @lvan not yet. Seems I need to install it. I’m looking into it now. I’ll let you know the result.